# DTE -> Getting Matching Brace in Visual Studio Macros?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-macros, braces

Is there any function available to get the position of the matching brace/quote/parenthesis/bracket for the current selection?

(I'm looking for the macro equivalent of the `Edit.GotoBrace` function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I totally forgot about the `DTE.ExecuteCommand` command.